# .one doesn't match Onenote file format specification

Tags: file-format, onenote

I'm going through the [MS-ONESTORE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff716740(v=office.12).aspx) specification trying to parse a `.one` file. The spec states that I ought to find `{8DFAB807-A83A-4AC0-
9393-E1DD0691CFB8}` at position 0x10, but instead I find `{15AC0EF3-FDFB-4295-9558-7CC34D9F220}` in one note, and `{3DE7BDCD-B2DC-4076-9C7A-6BA09C258768}` in another. I cannot find these guids anywhere in the docs. Can someone tell me where I am misinterpreting the spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at a specific example of a file rather than the structure definition.
Take a look at the following definition of the structure [Header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906213(v=office.12).aspx) which is linked from the page you referenced.

The specific element at 0x10 appears to be the unique identifier of the specific onenote file, so you'd expect it to be different in every file you parse.

Answer (score 2):

There's a sample one note parser on github
https://github.com/dropbox/onenote-parser
in case that helps you parse the file format.

Feel free to use it (apache license)

Try to see if the parser can read your document